VS Code disable hint popup (Everywhere, Forever, Always, Permanently, Irreversibly)
Please help as it drives me crazy

This thing pops up right where I need to see the code.
I tried many things – disabled all I could in settings
Went to settings.json:
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "telemetry.telemetryLevel": "off",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [
        "files.autoSave",
        "editor.formatOnPaste",
        "editor.insertSpaces",
        "editor.tabSize",
        "editor.hover.enabled",
        "notebook.lineNumbers",
        "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar",
        "editor.inlayHints.enabled"
    ],

    "notebook.editorOptionsCustomizations": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": false
    },
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
    "multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.executeAndFocusBelow",
            "sequence": [
                "notebook.cell.execute",
                "notebook.focusNextEditor"
            ]
        },{
            "command": "multiCommand.deleteAndFocusBelow",
            "sequence": [
                "notebook.cell.delete",
                "notebook.focusPreviousEditor",
                "notebook.focusNextEditor"
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "python.dataScience.jupyterServerURI": "http://localhost:8888/",
    "python.dataScience.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "python.dataScience.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
    "editor.hover.above": false,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "never",
    "accessibility.verbosity.hover": false,
    "editor.experimentalInlineEdit.showToolbar": "never",
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off",
    "editor.hover.enabled": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
    "workbench.editor.empty.hint": "hidden"
}

And it is still showing.
Tried changing "off" to false and false to "off".
And it is still showing.
Can it be because I edit remote notebook via vpn/ssh?

That looks like the parameter hint from Pylance, but I'm using Jedi so can't confirm. Try disabling editor.parameterHints.enabled. BTW, 'changing "off" to false and false to "off" ' wouldn't work; options have limited ranges. Instead go through the Settings menu so that you can see the correct range of choices.

BTW, regarding "disabled all I could in settings", please be specific so that we can rule things out. It might be moot for this question, but worth keeping in mind for the future at least.

Thank you @wjandrea – editor.parameterHints.enabled is exactly it!
Please make a formal answer, and I will accept it. Somehow the other question you've suggested was not coming up in my search, so answering it here would provide better keywords for searchers.
Also, "disabled all I could" is listed in provided config.
Thanks again

You should have a bar at the top of the question where you can click "Yes, this answers my question" or something like that. That'll mark it as a duplicate and future visitors will be pointed to the existing question. I don't think it's necessary for me to write a whole new answer, but thanks :)

Regarding "disabled all I could", it is moot, but just to clarify, by "specific" I meant, "what did you disable today, and what was already disabled that might be relevant?" There's also some stuff in there that's obviously not relevant like "editor.insertSpaces": false, so I also meant, "don't make us sift through all your settings, just show us the relevant ones." But again, this is moot for this question.
